# If a man gets raped, does he have to pay childsupport in practice?

Tags: germany

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYklPIrJsok) a Lawyer asserts that a man who got raped, by law, still has to pay child support to the child conceived from the rape. He also mentions that the man could demand the money back from the rapist, but if she can't pay he is out of luck.

I have doubts about this claim because it seems to go against the common sense and morality of most people. I would expect the state to pay in this case. I suspect that this case may be handled differently in practice, then in the law theory. For example, the mother could be deemed unable to raise a child, which could free the rape victim from having to pay child support.

Comment: Well, the put on hold message doesn't really tell me what I have to change about the question. I don't think it's offtopic, the claim is notable as we can see if we search google https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2014/09/02/statutory-rape-victim-child-support/14953965/

Comment: @Lichtbringer The question needs to be self contained. So you should add that link and a summary of the linked article. Furthermore, you should add why you think the claim might be untrue - what are you sceptical about. And finally: why did you tag the question with `Germany` when the case in your link is from the USA?

Comment: This may be much better off in Law.SE since there's not really anything to be skeptical about.  Also, your notable claim needs to be in the question, not a google search in the comments.  Remember that google results look different for different people because of their search algorithm.

Comment: @Lichtbringer In addition to Marzipanherz comment, Skeptics SE is for challenging specific claims; follow-on questions like "Does this happen a lot?" or "What happens in cases like this in Germany?" are off-topic. They might be better addressed to Law SE. Also minor English comment: I think you mean "in practice" rather than "in the praxis".

Comment: Yes, I meant in practise, thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: I've edited it a bit, but even then the video is in German and we can't confirm what he is saying.  I still don't think we can open it.  Really thinking this should be migrated.

Comment: You may want to put the exact quote from the video in your question, in order for answerers to have a definite claim to look at. Also, after a quick Google translate of the video transcription it seems that the guy says that the man would pay child support by default, but that either he could easily appeal them and not pay or that the child wouldn't stay with the mother. However, the translation wasn't great so that may not be what was said.

Comment: I think this should either go in Law SE if you want to know the exact legal situation in Germany or other countries, or Politics SE if you want to ask why this is and whether it ought to be changed.

Comment: In Russia, yes. In Israel also yes. In a recent case in Israel, the judge ruled that the man is entitled for compensation (he was not raped but lied to regarding contraceptives). But the compensation is very small, equal to the child support for a few months (while he would pay the child support for about 21 years). In Russia there were cases when the sperm donors whose identities were uncovered by bribed medics to the women had to pay child support.